# add segments to barchart (discrete x-axis) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to draw segments over each bar of a barchart with `ggplot2`. I know how to do this with a continuous X-axis, but not with this discrete axis.
What I did is a kind of "hack" by making-up a line with text.

It looks nice in the picture, but I don't get the legend for the "limit" metal concentration and, most of all, the length of the segment changes every time I zoom in or out.

Does anyone know which geometry could implement this better?
[image]

```
df = data.frame('metal'=c("Cu", "Fr", "Zn"), 'observed'=c(550, 60, 100), 'limit'=c(200, 150, 120))
ggplot(data=df) + aes(x=metal) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=observed), stat="identity", fill="grey") +
  geom_text(aes(y=limit, label="_____________"), size=rel(6), color="red")
```

**EDIT:**

The question is close to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158225/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-above-a-bar-chart-using-ggplot?lq=1) one

Comment: Use `geom_errorbar(aes(y=limit,ymin=limit,ymax=limit))` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158225/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-above-a-bar-chart-using-ggplot

Comment: @scoa thanks it works perfectly. Do you have a clue on how to get a "limit" legend though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158225/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-above-a-bar-chart-using-ggplot)

```
ggplot(data=df) + aes(x=metal) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=observed), stat="identity", fill="grey") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=limit,ymin=limit,ymax=limit,colour="limit"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach.

```
ggplot(data=df) + aes(x=metal) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=observed), stat="identity", fill="grey", color = "grey60") +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(y=limit), stat="identity", fill="transparent", color = "grey30") +
  geom_text(aes(y = limit +5), label = df$limit)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) thanks @lawyeR that's a really bright suggestion displaying the limit rectangles. I would like to accept both answers, but scoa's answer is closest from the initial request and displays my legend.