# Make a line separated by group in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay two sets of data that with be used in bar charts. The first is the main set of data and I want that to be the main focus. For the second dataset I want just a line marking where on the chart it would be. I can get close to what I want by doing this:

```
Tbl = data.frame(Factor = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 Percent = c(43,77,37,55))

Tbl2 = data.frame(Factor = c("a","b","c","d"),
                  Percent = c(58,68,47,63))

ggplot(aes(x = Factor, y = Percent), data = Tbl) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  ylim(0,100) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Factor, y = Percent), data = Tbl2,
           position = "stack", stat = "identity", fill = NA, color = "black") +
  theme_bw()
```

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZDON.png)

I believe I can accomplish what I want by using geom_vline if there is a way to separate it by groups. Another option I came up with is if it is possible to change the colors of the "sides" of the bars in the overlay to white while keeping the "top" of each bar chart as black.

An idea of what I want (Edited in paint)
[image: An idea of what I want (Edited in paint)]

Comment: @tjebo. sorry for reopening . But I wanted to post my solution I worked very long on it. In principle I agree if you mark as duplicate. :-)

Comment: Ok, that is good idea. Never thought this way. Thanks . Now go and mark as duplicate. I can't find the site!

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158225/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-above-a-bar-chart-using-ggplot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `geom_errorbar` where the ymin and ymax are the same values like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = Factor, y = Percent), data = Tbl) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  ylim(0,100) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Factor, ymin = Percent, ymax = Percent), data = Tbl2,
                stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `geom_point` with `shape = 95` (line) and the size adjusted to suit:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Tbl = data.frame(Factor = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 Percent = c(43,77,37,55))

Tbl2 = data.frame(Factor = c("a","b","c","d"),
                  Percent = c(58,68,47,63))

ggplot(aes(x = Factor, y = Percent), data = Tbl) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  ylim(0,100) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Factor, y = Percent), data = Tbl2,
           position = "stack", stat = "identity", color = "black", shape = 95, size = 30) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more using `geom_segment()`. Some would say to fancy, but anyway:
For this we have to extend `Tbl2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(aes(x = Factor, y = Percent), data = Tbl) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  ylim(0,100) +
  geom_segment(data = Tbl2 %>% 
                 mutate(x = c(0.55, 1.55, 2.55, 3.55),
                        xend = x+0.9), aes(x=x,xend=xend, y = Percent, yend=Percent), size=2)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: using segments, in those cases I prefer and recommend the use of a constant (e.g.,_w_) that both defines the width of your bars and the segment. In this case, as the default width of your bar is 0.9. I’d define w<-.45 (and bar width = 2*w). the segment needs to start at (1:4)-w and end at (1:4)+w

Comment: of smaller improvement suggestion your vector for x can be created simply with `.55:3.55`

Comment: This is a very good idea. And now you can imagine how tedious it was for me to position the lines in the correct position. It was just try and error. So I think you should please post your idea as an answer!

Comment: thanks. but I don’t think this merits an own answer. - if you want you can integrate into your own answer, or leave my comment as such